# Gradle Eclipse getting compile issues

Tags: eclipse, gradle, buildship

In my build.gradle file I have a dependency that is wrong

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter234')
```

When I do

```
gradle build
```

I get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter234:.
  Required by:
      project :
```

However in Eclipse when I run the task, I don't get a clear message.  I just get:
[image]

Note: I have Refresh the Gradle Project and get the same message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can right-click on the failed task (or ctrl-click on the Mac) and choose "Show Failures".

Or you can click on the little console icon (in the upper right corner of your screenshot) with the tooltip "Navigate to Console for this Execution"

Comment: Question was about trying to get more information about the failure so this answers it perfectly - thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use `mavenCentral` or `jcenter` as a repository. Neither of them has an artifact with groupId `org.springframework.boot` and artifactId `spring-boot-starter234` in your build script with the following line:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter234')
```

Therefore, `gradle` does not find it. One possible correct dependency for `spring-boot-starter` could be:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.0.2.RELEASE')
```

or pick another version that matches your project better from the [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter).